# Как передать List<класс> через аргументы

Tags: c#

Есть класс в котором собираю данные и записываю их в файл

```
public static class BaseLog
{
   private static readonly List<ClassName> DataBase = new List<ClassName>();

   public static void Save()
   {
      //...
      SaveDataBase.GO("Log.txt", DataBase);
   }
}
```

Есть отдельный класс который я хочу использовать для сохранения данных в файл.

```
public static class SaveDataBase
{
  public static void GO(string path, List<Type> _logs) // List<object> _logs
  {
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
       foreach (var item in _logs)
       {
          tw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том что из метода `SaveDataBase.GO` аргумент не правильно передаётся `List<Type> _logs` не удаётся преобразовать для класса.

Как передать `List<ClassName>` в аргументы? или это по другому называется, я точно не знаю прошу прощения.

```
public class ClassName
{
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public string Data{ get; set; } 

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return string.Format(Name, Data); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Ну так наверно не `List<Type> _logs`, а `List<ClassName> _logs`, не?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Ну так-то да, я хотел использовать один метод для каждого класса такого, а они все разные, и думал может есть какой-то определённы тип который можно указать чтобы выйти на отдельный класс.

Comment: Ну так и пишите в вопросе, что типов может быть несколько. Это называется [Generic](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/). Ответ вам дали, как в вашем случае подобное сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static class SaveDataBase<T>
{
  public static void GO(string path, List<T> _logs) 
  {
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
       foreach (T item in _logs)
       {
          tw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
       }
    }
  }
}

  ...
  SaveDataBase<ClassName>.GO("Log.txt", DataBase);
```

---

```
public static class SaveDataBase
{
  public static void GO<T>(string path, List<T> _logs) 
  {
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
       foreach (T item in _logs)
       {
          tw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
       }
    }
  }
}

  ...
  SaveDataBase.GO<ClassName>("Log.txt", DataBase);
```

Comment: ну или `SaveDataBase.Go<ClassName>(...)` как вариант :)

Comment: @Igor, А чем отличаются эти 2-а варианта?

Comment: @GooliveR Тем, что в первом случае шаблоном (темплэйтом) является класс, во втором - метод.